# Parse.com Is it possible to login using facebook while checking if the facebook user's email exists in a user in parse and if it does linking both?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, parse-platform

I'm having the following problem with the parse iOS SDK. In my app users can login using email (username)/password or facebook. When they use facebook the email (username) gets set automatically. But if the user logs in using email/password first and after logging out tries to login using facebook they get a duplicate account. My goal in this scenario is to link facebook to the previous account. Is there a way to check if the potential new user's email exist in parse database before creating a new account and if it exists then link both account? This way the user doesn't have to remember if they used facebook or email, they could use both seamlessly.

thanks.

Comment: were you able to accomplish this? Im having problem with some parse accounts adn long story short, I need to unlink fb from one account and link to an existing account...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic you need here is as follows:

1. Authenticate the user using Facebook
2. Get the additional information you need--e.g., read email from the Facebook graph API, or (in my case) prompt the user for a phone number (which you cannot get from Facebook)
3. Search the Parse user table for an account matching this piece of data (email address, phone number, etc.)
4. If a match is found, **and the user has authenticated against this identity***, link the accounts and login the user.
5. If no match is found, create a new Parse account for the user, using the email/phone identity

It's outlined in more detail here: [merge a user signed up by Facebook and already user signed up by email?](https://www.parse.com/questions/merge-a-user-signed-up-by-facebook-and-already-user-signed-up-by-email). There's sample JS code but the idea should be the same for iOS.

*Pay close attention to what the Parser says in the last answer.  If a Facebook user claims to own an email address or a phone number, you need to independently verify that they own that account (by e.g. sending an authorization link or code).

Comment: This is great, but I'm not clear how we're actually supposed to do the "link the accounts and login the user" in step 4. In our case, we have an anonymous user, so "link the accounts" just makes my Facebook user the anonymous user. And if the existing user was created by username/password, there's no way for me to get the password. So how do we actually execute step 4?

Comment: Hi @mrwheet, I think the code you're looking for is in [Parse.FacebookUtils](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.FacebookUtils.html). I'm not sure what you mean by "anonymous user"--the idea of the logic I posted is that you're linking a Facebook account with a PFUser account in your Parse user table. You don't need the password to call `Parse.FacebookUtils.link`. HTH!

Comment: Our app uses the anonymous user (automatically created at launch), so that people have some functionality before signing up. When I use the FB utils to link, it can link to the anonymous user (which is PFUser.currentUser()), but can't link to the user I've recalled from the users table. That's what's confusing... (and frustrating). And I can't find a way to make the user I've recalled from the users table become PFUser.currentUser(), except by logging in, which requires the password.

Comment: Hi @mrwheet, I'm a little confused about exactly which case you're stuck on, since the decision tree is rather large here. Has the user authenticated successfully using FB? Do they have an existing account in your app? Have they authenticated against this account? Which order are the authentications happening in (FB first, or your app first)? Are the accounts linked? (assuming no here)

Comment: You refer to a user you recalled from the users table, which suggests the user previously registered in your app. Have them log into that account (using a username and password or whatever auth scheme your app uses), then authenticate against FB (they can tap a button that says "link your FB account"), then the final step is to link the two using `Parse.FacebookUtils.link`.

Comment: Well there are two cases: 1) where they have a user/pw account already, and 2) where they sign up using FB in the first place (no user/pw). I see that, with case 1, I should ask for the pw after I authenticate via FB—I thought maybe I could avoid asking... For case 2 my problem is if/when they log out. Since I get them in without a pw, I want them to be able to re-login without a pw, but I can't see how to do that, since I can't re-link (to the user created by the original FB signup) without a pw, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Actually I think there are three cases. 1) They have a user/pw account already, and are logged into it; 2) they have a user/pw account, but aren't logged in and authenticate against FB first; 3) they sign up using FB first, with no existing account. For (1) they should tap "Link to FB" and you can link the accounts easily. For (2) after they auth against FB, ask them either for the account password or else to tap a link in an email to prove ownership, then link the accounts. (I use phone numbers, not email, and I send a one-off code via SMS.)

Comment: For (3), you have two options. You could require them to create a password for their account, so that they can login using username/pw in the future. Or you could skip this step, which would require them to always login using FB in the future. If they always login using FB there should be no need for a password. The Parse infrastructure will create a corresponding Parse user account for the FB user and link it to the FB account for you. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, except for that last statement: "The Parse infrastructure will create a corresponding Parse user account for the FB user and link it to the FB account". While that does happen, in my experience, it does not become a canonical Parse user, so to speak (i.e., I don't get linked to that user next time). Rather, I get a new Parse account every time. I need this user to be persistent across logins/logouts.

Comment: One solution offered on another thread is to use the FB email to recall/query the existing Parse user (i.e., the one FB created with the last login) and copy its data into the newly created user, then delete the old user via a PFCloud call. In fact, if I recall correctly (I read it at some point during my scavenging for solutions), this is basically what FB recommends...

Comment: I ask the user for a phone number when they create an account using FB, then use that to create a new Parse account, and link the two. (You could do the same with the email address.) This way you don't need to allow FB to create the Parse account. It ends up working the same way as option (1) I described.

Comment: Okay, but this is what I don't understand; how do you make sure you have that Parse account again if the user logs out and tries to login again? In my experience, if the user logs out (after FB signup), when they come back again, Parse will create a new account. The "link" doesn't seem to persist across logouts. So I have a user in the Users table, and I have an authenticated FB user; both have the same email, but they're not automatically linked.
(Mind you, it did work as expected at one time, before changes to FB functionality for iOS 9—i.e., the problems I'm having are new.)

Comment: Auth the user against FB using `FBLoginManager.login()`. Confirm there's no matching account. Create a new account using `new Parse.User()`. Log the user in by returning `user.getSessionToken()` from the cloud code, then calling `Parse.User.become(token)` on the frontend. Then link the accounts by calling `FBLoginManager.getCredentials()` and then `Parse.FacebookUtils.link()`. The next time the user logs in using FB, calling `Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn()` with the FB `authData` will log in the Parse user.

Comment: One small caveat: in order to "confirm there's no matching account" I needed to create a separate Class linking the User ID with the FB ID. Then I perform a lookup in that table using the FB ID to see if the FB account is already linked. There may be an easier way to do this.

Comment: "There may be an easier way to do this." One would kinda hope so! :) 
But thanks for your help—your last reply goes further into a solution than anything I've found elsewhere.

Comment: Awesome, lemme know if you're still stuck. I want to post a code snippet but there's a LOT of code and it's very spread out, among a bunch of methods that tie into the UI and also on the backend, which makes doing so hard. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a simple query on the User table to see if a user already exists with the same username. If it does, you'll want to link the Facebook data to this account. Their docs outline how to do this with the SDK: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers-link/iOS

Answer (score -1):

It will link "user" with Facebook account easily.

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_relationships", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"];
    [PFFacebookUtils linkUser:user permissions:permissionsArray block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        //do anything
    }];
```