# How to Link Facebook account with existing user in Parse on iOS

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, authentication, hyperlink, account

Does anyone know how to link facebook account with existing user in Parse? (Parse 1.8.3, Facebook sdk 4.6).

Comment: I found [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/merge-a-user-signed-up-by-facebook-and-already-user-signed-up-by-email) on the Parse website. Please pay special attention to the warning from the guys in Parse.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663807/parse-com-is-it-possible-to-login-using-facebook-while-checking-if-the-facebook/34712418, there's some more info there.